# SQLite - How to remove rows that have a string cell value contained in other rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table in a SQLite database:

```
-----------------------------
id | string |...other columns
-----------------------------
01 |     AA |...
02 |    AAB |...
03 |     AB |...
04 |    BAB |...
```

What I need to do is to remove all the rows where the cell value of the column "string" is contained in any other row.

In the example above, row id-1 string is contained in row id-2 string and row id-3 string is contained in both row id-2 and id-4 strings.

So the final result should be:

```
-----------------------------
id | string |...other columns
-----------------------------
02 |    AAB |...
04 |    BAB |...
```

Is there an easy query to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` (*case–insensitive*):

```
delete from table
where exists (select * from table t where t.string like '%' || table.string || '%')
```

or `instr` (*case–sensitive*):

```
delete from table
where exists (select * from table t where instr(t.string, table.string) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer notulyses, but isn't LIKE a bit fuzzy in comparing strings? I need to remove only the rows that their string value is contained in other rows. The function to compare should be the same as string.Contains() in c# for example.

Comment: That actually works!... so simple it makes my little SQL knowledge vanish completely :( you have my vote thanks!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon... I tried your query changing the "delete" by "select *" to actually see what were the rows being deleted, but when I change it back to "delete" I get a SQL syntax error on the "t". I can't figure out what is the correct syntax :(

Comment: @nutulysses, thanks for the quick reply but that doesn't seem to delete any row. Changing "delete" by "select *" also returns 0 matches

Comment: select * from table t where instr(ngram, t.ngram) > 0
returns 0 matches

Comment: @FranCasadome : take a more precise look at the query. You shouldn't give an _alias_ to the outer query table , but give it to the inner query table and prefix all inner query table fields with _alias_ and outer query fields with _table name_.

Comment: @nutulysses my bad, you are right, I didn't notice the "table.string" update

Comment: @FranCasadome : I can finally go to sleep with a  peaceful concsience))